# how to bind collection of object to text boxes in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

here my case things are bit complex  even not sure how to describe.

I have a class called Employee. Employee has an other object called Address Structure I given below.

```
 public class Employee 
 {
 public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
 }

public class Address
{
public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

in wpf I am able to bind the data like

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Employee.Addresses/Text}" Margin="0,0,0,29" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
```

Even if I have 3 address  I am getting only the first one. Even I he tried giving index like Address[1]/Text. Its not working can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of a relationship, it would be better to use an `ItemsControl` like a [ListBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listbox?view=netframework-4.7.1) or a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listview?view=netframework-4.7.1) and bind the `ItemsSource` to the collection of `Address` objects.

You can define a `DataTemplate` to format each individual `Address` object in the collection.

One final note--if the collection of `Address` objects changes, those changes will not be propagated to the UI unless they are contained within a collection which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface. Usually, the [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.1) suffices for this.